# Cannot run migration:generate : "Missing required argument: dataSource"

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have 3 scripts in my package.json and they work as expected :

```js
    "migration:create": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:create ./libs/database/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migrate": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run -d ./datasource.ts",
    "migration:revert": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:revert -d ./datasource.ts",
```

but for some reason I cannot add a "migration:generate" like this one :

```js
    "migration:generate": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate ./libs/database/migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

It cause this error : "Missing required argument: dataSource"

In my root directory I have datasource.ts

```js
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const connectionSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'xx',
  password: 'xx',
  database: 'xx',
  logging: true,
  entities: [__dirname + 'libs/database/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: [__dirname + 'libs/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations',
});
```

And in libs/database/src/database.module I have the typeorm config :

```js
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
        entities: [join(__dirname, 'entities', '*.entity/*{.ts,.js}')],
        migrationsTableName: 'migrations_table',
        migrations: [join(__dirname, '/../', 'migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}')],
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: false,
      }),
    }),
```

My entities are in: libs/database/src/entities
The migrations files are in: libs/database/migrations

I don't get where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not add data source reference into your script
should be like `"migration:generate": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate  -d ./datasource.ts ./libs/database/migrations/$npm_config_name"`

```
        "typeorm": "node --loader ts-node/esm ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm",
        "db:drop": "yarn typeorm schema:drop -d ./ormconfig.ts",
        "db:create": "sh -c 'yarn typeorm migration:create ./src/modules/db/migrations/$0'",
        "db:run": "yarn typeorm migration:run -d ./ormconfig.ts",
        "db:revert": "yarn typeorm migration:revert -d ./ormconfig.ts",
        "db:generate": "sh -c 'yarn typeorm migration:generate -d ./ormconfig.ts ./src/modules/db/migrations/$0'",
```